# How to receive data on my Computer from an android application

Tags: android, web-services

I have to connect my Android device to my computer via internet connection. How do i go about doing it?
Create a webservice which the application talks to? ( But how to receive the data from webservice on my computer? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.  Look up REST APIs.  You can either run the web service in the cloud somewhere and let both the Android and the PC connect as clients, or you can put a LAMP stack on your PC and run the web server and database right there.

If you allow direct USB connections, then you can also get the data off using ADB or Android File Transfer, without even using your app directly.